# Incorrect Order, Extra Cert Lets Encrypt Apache 2.433

Tags: apache-2.4, lets-encrypt

im having issues using a webhook and think it might be my SSL cert. When I use sslabs.com to test my server i get a warning about "Incorrect Order, Extra Certs"

these are the files in my letsencrypt/live folder:

cert.pem
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem

Any idea whats causing this issue and how i can resolve?

I found this here:

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/incorrect-order-and-extra-certificate-error/8759

but not sure if this applies to me.

Comment: What are the relevant configuration lines in your Apache configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use either

```
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXX/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXX/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXX/chain.pem
```

or (with your modern-enough Apache >= 2.4.8)

```
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXX/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXX/privkey.pem
```

in your configuration, but **not**

```
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXX/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXX/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXX/fullchain.pem
```

Note that `fullchain` is the concatenation of `cert` and `chain`, so the bad variant has the leaf cert twice.